# Наложение цвета на background-image

Tags: css, background

[image: На фоне вместо цвета градиент, линии заданы отдельным url, и для них нужно сделать наложение цвета]у меня есть header, как наложить цвет именно на картинку в фоне?

```css
header{
   width:100%;
   height:100vh;
   background: url("../img/png/header_left_lines.png") no-repeat left bottom -28px , radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(62,80,141,1) 0%,rgba(24,32,59,1) 88%,rgba(24,32,59,1) 88%);
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
```

Comment: Прикрепите, пожалуйста "header_left_lines.png".  Есть идея реализации, но без изображения не могу понять корректна ли она для вашей задачи...

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Из-за отсутствия прозрачности градиент перекрывает изображение... Так и задумывалось?

Comment: В общем должно быть так. У хедера есть градиент, по левую и правую сторону от него расположены эти линии. Конкретно для этих линий я бы хотел сделать наложение цвета. Возможно ли реализовать такое по средствам одного background ? Или же придётся применять абсолютное позиционирование к псевдоэлементам?

Comment: Думаю что нужно разделить фон и линии тогда может и выйдет что-то адекватное, наработки по наложению (может поможет) https://jsfiddle.net/v2r8jw6e/24/ (возможно я не прав и можно как то сделать это проще)

Comment: Возможно вам нужен background-blend-mode. Вот тут я немного поигрался с вашей картинкой goo.gl/VJWNJ8

Answer (score 1):

Надо просто указать вторым фоном после запятой

если что то не ясно : https://jsfiddle.net/a2bk4yjh/3/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-eN2cEGCr2FI/UQg-KzEzdMI/AAAAAAAABLE/s2fZGiCozuU/s1600/XLR+to+RCA+Diagram.png), rgba(31, 40, 71, .8);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```